# Azure Synapse: Can I import modules from other notebooks in the same worksapce?

Tags: azure-synapse

In normal Python project we might have a parent py file that imports from a sibling or child folder/module (initialised by `__init__.py`, `from .folder import module` etc.

Is there a way to do this using Synapse notebooks within a given (ex. `dev`) workspace?

Ex. I would like to create a notebook/python module for use in logging - a wrapper to wrap functions. I don't want to have to have to copy-paste this module into 20 different notebooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use something called notebook reference
You can use %run  magic command to reference another notebook within current notebook's context. All the variables defined in the reference notebook are available in the current notebook. %run magic command supports nested calls but not support recursive calls. You will receive an exception if the statement depth is larger than five.

Example: `%run /<path>/Notebook1 { "parameterInt": 1, "parameterFloat": 2.5, "parameterBool": true, "parameterString": "abc" }`.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-development-using-notebooks#notebook-reference)

Comment: Thank you! Will read through those docs, but does this run the entire contents of the notebook? I don't want to execute the notebook, only access functions/variables from within it. (EDIT: Context here being that I might want to run a notebook to get a variable, from a notebook that is not just a "source" for variables, if that makes sense -> IE, it might be an actual notebook called in a pipeline to perform a task)

Comment: Yes, I believe you can do it. Since it is reference which is similar to import a module.

Comment: Per my understanding, these notebooks have to be published into the live mode. My experiments proved to be a bit tricky when the team was working on multiple solution branches simultaneously.

Comment: Just want to add that you do not need to publish notebooks to use them in another notebook. For testing purpose, you can ckeckbox "Enable unpublished notebook reference" in notebook properties for the notebook in which you want to use other notebook.